# Error on init of custom class in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c

I use the following code to alloc and init a class in objective c. The class is a cocoa touch class. I try to initialize the class with the code below.

```
   MyClass *myClass;
   myClass=[MyClass alloc];
   myClass=[MyClass init];
```

It crashes at

```
myClass=[MyClass init];
```

saying

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** +[MyClass<0x100b075d0> init]: cannot init a class object.'
```

If i use

```
myClass=[[MyClass alloc] init];
```

It works. Any idea why this happens?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[MyClass alloc]` calls the `alloc` method on the class `MyClass`. It returns an *instance* of `MyClass`, ready to be initialised, which you do by calling `init` on the returned instance.

Classically you write `[[MyClass alloc] init]` in Objective-C because there's nothing you can or should be doing between allocating and initialising.

In your code, `[MyClass init]` is treating init like a class method, which it is not.

```
MyClass *myClass;
myClass = [MyClass alloc];
myClass = [myClass init];
```

Would probably work (note I'm calling `init` on `myClass`, not `MyClass`, but it would upset any future readers and make them wonder why you're not just doing it the normal way.

Comment: You are write i wrote MyClass by accident instead of myClass. Now i noticed it by reading your answer. Thank you!

Comment: write=*right My bad

Comment: You should still use `[[MyClass alloc] init]` its idiomatic - other folks reading your code will expect it to be done that way.